# Regular expression , extract second or third occurence

Tags: regex, wordpress

I'm writing a regular expression in autoblogged plugin for wordpress to extract the second occurrence of matches. my code is

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5" border="0">
<tbody><tr>
<td class="plandescription" colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="plandescription">Accréditations :                                        <img width="32" height="32" align="absmiddle" src="http://www.congres-medical.com/modules/3c01_Event/images/credit_off.png">
                                                              </td>
<td bgcolor="#F1F1F1" class="plandescription">0 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#f1f1f1" class="plandescription"><strong>Public concerné:</strong></td>
<td width="67%" bgcolor="#f1f1f1" class="plandescription">Professionnel</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#f1f1f1" class="plandescription"><strong>Audience:</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="#f1f1f1" class="plandescription">Internationnale</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#f1f1f1" class="plandescription"><strong>Visiteurs/Participants:</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="#f1f1f1" class="plandescription">550</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#f1f1f1" class="plandescription"><strong>Conférenciers:</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="#f1f1f1" class="plandescription">n.r</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#f1f1f1" class="plandescription"><strong>Exposants:</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="#f1f1f1" class="plandescription">n.r</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#f1f1f1" class="plandescription"><strong>Type d’événement:</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="#f1f1f1" class="plandescription"><span class="plandate">Conférence / Séminaire</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" bgcolor="#f1f1f1" class="plandescription"><strong>Secteur principal:</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="#f1f1f1"><a class="link_noir" href="http://www.congres-medical.com/modules.php?name=3c01_Event&amp;op=secteur&amp;id_sousrub=53" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">DIABETOLOGIE</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="middle" bgcolor="#f1f1f1" class="plandescription"><strong>Secteurs concernés:</strong></td>
<td>
           <a class="secteurficheevent" href="http://www.congres-medical.com/modules.php?name=3c01_Event&amp;op=secteur&amp;id_sousrub=9" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Cardiologie</a> -<a class="secteurficheevent" href="http://www.congres-medical.com/modules.php?name=3c01_Event&amp;op=secteur&amp;id_sousrub=53" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Diabétologie</a> -<a class="secteurficheevent" href="http://www.congres-medical.com/modules.php?name=3c01_Event&amp;op=secteur&amp;id_sousrub=40" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Pharmacologie</a> -</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I need to extract:

- 0 for $1 matches
- public for $2 matches
- Internationnale for $3 matches

I have used this regular expression

```
>([\w\m]+)<
```

but it extracts only the first occurrence. What should I do to extract all occurrences and use them with: `$1`, `$2`, `$3` for autoblogged plugin in wordpress?

Comment: where is the actual code?

Comment: what is `\m` in the regex engine your using?

Comment: there is my actual code  >([\w\m]+)<

Comment: `udience:<[^<>]+><[^<>]+>\n+<[^<>]+>([^<>]+)<` i have used this regular expression to get for exemple the "Internationale" and it work in http://regexpal.com/ but it does not work in Autoblogged wordpress plugin